# Embedding a Silverlight video player on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, video, embed

Is there a way to embed my custom silverlight player onto a Facebook wall? I've seen the info for embedding a Flash player but I'd love to find a way for this Silverlight player to work as well.

Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

No Facebook only supports embedding .swf and .mp4 files for videos.

Comment: Facebook supports .swf and .mp4 in their player but I'd like to embed a link to my own Silverlight player that supports a wider variety of formats.

Comment: Send that as a feature request to Facebook Developer page, but it isn't currently supported.